# CActiveForm отображение данных из связанной таблицы

Tags: php, yii

Есть таблицы `attribute` и `category`. Между ними описаны связи многие-ко-многим в таблице `category_has_attribute` c полями: `category_id`, `attribute_id`, `for_filter`.

В модели Attribute прописана связь с категориями:

```
 public function relations() {
    return array(
        'category'  => array(
             self::MANY_MANY,
             'Category',
             '{{category_has_attribute}}(category_id, attribute_id)'
        )
    );
 }
```

Теперь во вьюхе мне необходимо отобразить чекбокс для установки `for_filter`. Пробую так:

```
 <?php echo $form->checkBoxRow($model, 'for_filter')?>
```

или

```
 <?php echo $form->checkBoxRow($model, 'category->for_filter')?>
```

оба варианта естественно не работают.
Как использовать `CActiveForm::checkBoxRow()` чтобы если чекбокс "отмечен" на уровне базы, то он выводился отмеченным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этой статье хорошо все описано
[Статья](http://www.elisdn.ru/blog/26/chekboksi-dlia-sviazei-mnogie-ko-mnogim-v-yii)

Comment: Спасибо! Я именно так и сделал в итоге. Даже не знал, что это где-то уже описано)